# How to extract subdirectory from tar into another tar without `sudo`?

Tags: tar, compression, archive

##### Given

A tar file with `rootfs` where all permissions and ownerships are set.

##### Expected

A tar file with content of subdirectory, let's say `usr/local/lib` where permissions and ownerships are retained.

##### Known way

Decompress the directory with `-p` using `sudo` and then compress it back into another tar.

##### Question

Is there a better way to do it without invoking sudo to just copy the content of the directory out into another tar file?